# Reorder and Group Multiple Columns by Regex/pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following:

```
a_aa a_ab a_ac b_aa b_ab b_ac
2    3    3    3     1    2
3    4    1    1     3    1
```

Desired outcome:

```
a_aa b_aa a_ab b_ab a_ac b_ac
2    3    3    1     3    2
3    1    4    3     1    1
```

Code with data:

```
d <- "a_aa a_ab a_ac b_aa   b_ab b_ac
2    3    3    3     1    2
3    4    1    1     3    1"
dd <- read.table(textConnection(object = d), header = T)
```

My current solution is manual:

```
    dd %>% select(a_aa, b_aa, a_ab, b_ab, a_ac, b_ac)
```

however, is onerous when number of columns is large. Any ideas how to do this kind of column ordering with grouping (e.g. sequence a_etc1, b_etc1, a_etc2, b_etc2)? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to solve your problem:

```
dd[order(gsub(".+_", "", names(dd)))]

# or

dd %>%
  select(order(gsub(".+_", "", names(.))))


  a_aa b_aa a_ab b_ab a_ac b_ac
1    2    3    3    1    3    2
2    3    1    4    3    1    1
```

Comment: This is very elegant, worked on a large set. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- "a_aa  a_ab    a_ac    b_aa    b_ab    b_ac
2   3   1   3   3   2
3   1   3   4   1   1"
dd <- read.table(textConnection(object = d), header = T)

colnames(dd) %>% 
  str_split("_") %>% 
  map_chr(~.x[2]) %>% 
  unique() -> vars

dd %>% 
  select(ends_with(all_of(vars)))
#>   a_aa b_aa a_ab b_ab a_ac b_ac
#> 1    2    3    3    3    1    2
#> 2    3    4    1    1    3    1
```

If you don't want to use other tidyverse libraries than dplyr, you can do

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

d <- "a_aa  a_ab    a_ac    b_aa    b_ab    b_ac
2   3   1   3   3   2
3   1   3   4   1   1"
dd <- read.table(textConnection(object = d), header = T)

colnames(dd) %>% 
  strsplit("_") %>% 
  sapply(\(.x) .x[2]) %>% 
  unique() -> vars

dd %>% 
  select(ends_with(all_of(vars)))
#>   a_aa b_aa a_ab b_ab a_ac b_ac
#> 1    2    3    3    3    1    2
#> 2    3    4    1    1    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Good to see you here!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:

We first create a function using two additional packages:

1. `stringi` for its `str_reverse` function (advantage:it is vectorized)
2. `gtools` for its `mixedsort` function

Then we apply it to our dataframe `df` with `rename_with`:

```
library(dplyr)

# the function
my_function <- function(df){
  x <- stringi::stri_reverse(colnames(df))
  y <- gtools::mixedsort(x)
  stringi::stri_reverse(y)
}


df %>% 
  rename_with(., ~my_function(df))
```

```
  a_aa b_aa a_ab b_ab a_ac b_ac
1    2    3    3    3    1    2
2    3    4    1    1    3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
dd[,order(gsub(".*\\_(\\w+$)", "\\1", names(dd)))]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! What is the purpose of "+$" in your regex? This worked as well: dd[,order(gsub(".*\\_(\\w)", "\\1", names(dd)))]. Interestingly, in a large dataset with "+" characters in some column names, the sorting was not accomplished when "+$" was used.